# Unable to capture variables in SAML SSO response body

Tags: html, xpath, single-sign-on, saml

I have to capture 'RelayState' and 'SAMLResponse' values from the following response body. But it's not capturing these values when I try following xPath expressions. Is there a workaround to capture these variable to use in a Jmeter script? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Xpath queries used:-

```
//input[@type='hidden'][@name='RelayState']/@value
//input[@type='hidden'][@name='SAMLResponse']/@value
```

---

Response Body

```
<form method='post' action='localhost:9443/store/acs'>; <p> <!--$params--> <input type='hidden' name='RelayState' value='%2Fstore%2Fpages%2Fgc-landing'> <input type='hidden' name='SAMLResponse' value='PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHNhbWwycDpSZXNwb25zZ‌​SBEZXN0aW5hdGlvbj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6OTQ0My9Xh0Q2xhc3NSZWY+PC9zYW1sMjpBdXRo‌​bkNvbnRleHQ+PC9zYW1sMjpBdXRoblN0YXRlbWVudD48L3NhbWwyOkFzc2VydGlvbj48L3NhbWwycDpSZ‌​XNwb25zZT4='> <!--$additionalParams--> <button type='submit'>POST</button></p></form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784422/an-error-was-encountered-with-the-requested-page-in-jmeter-even-capture-variab 
can you loo into this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with Regular Expression Extractor?

Post Processors -> Regular Expression Extractor: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

and use below regular expression to get values for 'RelayState' and 'SAMLResponse'

```
name='RelayState' value='([^"]+)'
name='SAMLResponse' value='([^"]+)'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784422/an-error-was-encountered-with-the-requested-page-in-jmeter-even-capture-variab

can you pls look into this ?

Answer (score 0):

Despite what some people say about regular expression extractors vs xpath, I prefer to use regex as it has smaller impact on overall test execution. You can apply regular expression like this on unescaped body, to get those values:

```
name=\"SAMLResponse\" value=\"([^"]+)\"
```