# "An error was encountered with the requested page" in jmeter even capture variables by using regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I have used jmeter to record login flow of application , when i re run it there are some requests failing so i fetch dynamic values from earlier responses and supplies those values to subsequent requests

I am facing some issues there is State token in requests but format of this is changing dynamically  so because of that when i rerun some time requests are passing some time failing

Here those are

**Fail case**

```
{"stateToken":"00UaBoY\x2D81AIL32Nz9qmUJrIarSv3OgfUdd8FHGSkb"}
{"stateToken":"00C8O4pt\x2DcSPEzHrt69zqmEGta9KbjdwywEVdkICku"}
{"stateToken":"00JgMsy7\x2DzXDP0gxaeWv4dj8EguFTWtnLxV\x2DBKTkIq"}
```

**Working case**

```
{"stateToken":"00fswJVHKpW7dNhNVK0bRclBBrsuMLHBBevJ8IS1Wz"}
{"stateToken":"00ZVZXpSJn7v3lxNTrEqy1mAGydgroO5apvoTlWH2u"}
```

My regular expression for capture state token is `stateToken":"(.+?)"`

what is issue here ?

the second issue is saml,relay state are not working even regax working fine in regax tester , i am getting "An error was encountered with the requested page". in debug sampler those 2 variables are getting and passed ( screenshot is attached )

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anyone have ideas related above 2 issues please give some ideas to sort out this

Answer (score 0):

Your failing requests`tokens have`\x`.

You will have to encode the value and send the request.

1. In HTTP Request
   Check the filed `URL encode?`
   [image]
2. Encoding the value with function

Comment: I gave URL Encode tick and re run it , still same issue

Comment: Can you please verify the values in the View Result Tree --> Request Tab ? Encode the value using JMeter function  (UrlEncode)[https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode]and compare if the values are comparable.

Comment: {"stateToken":"00JgMsy7\x2DzXDP0gxaeWv4dj8EguFTWtnLxV\x2DBKTkIq"} i want to remove "\x2D" from above ( my regax was stateToken":"(.+?)" but its not working ) can you guide to remove ?

\x2D is changing in token some time its coming front part and some times its coming later part of token

Comment: need to install plugin manager in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in your application, I don't think it's JMeter issue, presumably it's due to presence of these `\x2D` characters (may be incorrect work of [unicode escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#3.3))

I don't know what does your application expect instead of this `\x2D` try to inspect the [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) code of the application to see what it does do the tokens, when you figure this out you can replicate this token conversion logic in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: {"stateToken":"00JgMsy7\x2DzXDP0gxaeWv4dj8EguFTWtnLxV\x2DBKTkIq"} i want to remove "\x2D" from above ( my regax was stateToken":"(.+?)" but its not working ) can you guide to remove ? \x2D is changing in token some time its coming front part and some times its coming later part of token

Comment: Fail Case

002KljInsq318mkPTkDTuJ06eLSxIQmVga\x2DSuvHmDe

{"stateToken":"00UaBoY\x2D81AIL32Nz9qmUJrIarSv3OgfUdd8FHGSkb"}

{"stateToken":"003LYZGSYKn3io1ocOwCBNcp2I\x2Dt8UbkdBfruaC6C0"}

{"stateToken":"00C8O4pt\x2DcSPEzHrt69zqmEGta9KbjdwywEVdkICku"}
{"stateToken":"00JgMsy7\x2DzXDP0gxaeWv4dj8EguFTWtnLxV\x2DBKTkIq"}




Working

{"stateToken":"00fswJVHKpW7dNhNVK0bRclBBrsuMLHBBevJ8IS1Wz"}
{"stateToken":"00ZVZXpSJn7v3lxNTrEqy1mAGydgroO5apvoTlWH2u"}

Comment: cant we exclude \x2D by regular expression extractor ?